# Does Strongarm need to be enabled on Production site using Features?

Tags: features

I'm using Features in order to make my site content configuration exportable for purposes of staging my server. I'll be using Strongarm to make some of the site variables exposed for management in a feature.

Does the Strongarm module need to be enabled on my live production site in order for the active features to be able to present and set the variables which I have encapsulated within them?

Or, does Strongarm only need to be enabled on my dev server where and when I am creating my features components?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you need the strongarm module on production site as the module implements `hook_features_revert` and `hook_features_rebuild` which is needed to do any reverts to the variables you have featurized or to apply new variables that u have introduced in your feature.

Comment: The features created that uses strongarm will actually be created with a dependency to the strongarm module